# How do I fix this error (in the body is all required info)

Tags: android

This is my first time trying to use Android studio. So sorry if this is a stupid question.  
 When I try to sync the Gradle I get this error

> Could not find method buildTypes() for arguments [build_cvj92yjljuq3g0b4nqjuesngb$_run_closure2@6cd68e7f] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.swiftr.tl"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id: 'app_id',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
        ]
    }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.15.0, 3.99.99]'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the `buildTypes` block inside the `android` block.

You have:

```
android {
    ...
}

buildTypes {
    ...
}
```

It should look like:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        ...
    }
}
```